# how to force rack:session + sinatra to read "rack.session" from params instead of cookies

Tags: ruby, oauth, sinatra, rack, cors

I am dealing with oauth 1.0 (twitter and flickr). Website works at port 80 and oauth server works at port 8080

Algorithm:

1. send ajax request to oauth server to check if user have valid access_token
2. open authorization window if user have no access_token or access_token is expired
3. save access_token in user's session at the oauth server
4. send sharing data to the oauth server

It uses sinatra + rack:session + rack::session::sequel + sqlite to store sessions. It sends `Set-Cookie: rack.session=id` in each response

I am using 2 types of request: crossdomain ajax with jquery and usual request with window.open. I have a big security problem passing cookies to crossdomain ajax request.

No matter that server's response headers contains

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

chromium will throw security error:

> Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

I want to avoid this problem by passing rack.session=id to post data and load it:

```
before "/twitter/connect.json" do
  session = Rack::Session::something(params["rack.session"])
end
```

But I cant find in documentation how to do this

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to which server is doing what. Which server is the `before` block running on? When you write "save access_token in user's session at the oauth server" does that mean save via the database? "It uses sinatra + rack:session…", 'it' means the website? Sorry to be a pedantic but the clarity will help answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rack::Session::Abstract::ID` has an option called `cookie_only` that [allows the session id to be passed in via the params](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L275). However, it [defaults to true](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L205), and most session middleware implementations [don't bother to override it](https://github.com/migrs/rack-session-sequel/blob/master/lib/rack/session/sequel.rb#L10-L11).

Your best bet is probably to monkey patch `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID` to default `cookie_only` to false.

```
Rack::Session::Abstract::ID::DEFAULT_OPTIONS.merge! :cookie_only => false
```